# How to control shadow of element with CSS?

Tags: css, css-animations

I am playing around with animating shadow. I want it to work like this: When i click on box, i want class of "shadow" to be added. When it does, i want to animate shadow like it is lifting up, and when removed class, i want shadow to disappear the same way it appears (reverse). I have created keyframes and set the blur and opacity to change. 
One thing i notice is, the animation is not smooth, it goes by steps. Why is it so? I want shadow animation to be smooth.
Second, how to create that shadow will also disappear in reverse when class is removed?

Here is my code so far:

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box");
function shadowHandle(){
 box.classList.toggle("shadow");
}

box.addEventListener("click", shadowHandle);
```

```css
body{
  margin: 100px;
}
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shadow { /* Webkit */
 0%   { box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
  25%  { box-shadow: -1px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
 50%  { box-shadow: -2px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
  75%  { box-shadow: -3px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); }
 100% { box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
}
@-moz-keyframes shadow { /* Webkit */
 0%   { box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
  25%  { box-shadow: -1px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
 50%  { box-shadow: -2px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
  75%  { box-shadow: -3px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); }
 100% { box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
}
@keyframes shadow { /* Webkit */
 0%   { box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
  25%  { box-shadow: -1px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
 50%  { box-shadow: -2px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
  75%  { box-shadow: -3px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); }
 100% { box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
}
.shadow {
 animation:         shadow 2s forwards; /* CSS3 */
 -moz-animation:    shadow 2s forwards; /* Firefox */
 -webkit-animation: shadow 2s forwards; /* Webkit */
}
```

```html
<div class="box shadow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Keyframes. This is much more easier with transition

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box");
function shadowHandle(){
 box.classList.toggle("shadow");
}

box.addEventListener("click", shadowHandle);
```

```css
body{
  margin: 100px;
}
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  
}

.box.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
 }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Hm, i like this simple solution. I guess i can control blur and opacity here? Just by adding more parameters with ","?

Comment: Ofc, you can change the opacity by changing the last value of rgba().
Also you can change the size.

Answer (score 1):

I think using a transition is the way to go here. It will animate back "mid-animation".

here's an example with :hover, but you can use an added class as well.

```css
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: silver;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover {
  box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply achieved through `transition`
Follow the snippet below:

Add the box-shadow to class `shadow`
now add CSS `transition` to the `.box.

`transition: all 1s linear`
This will animate **all** css properties which can be animated
For a duration of **1s**
In a **linear** rate. Other values are `ease` `ease-in` `ease-out`, etc

Play around and find out.

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box");

function shadowHandle() {
  box.classList.toggle("shadow");
}

box.addEventListener("click", shadowHandle);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 100px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.shadow {
  box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: The thing i miss here is that i do not have control over blur. I want blur to be hard at beginning and soft at end (when animation reaches end). Is it possible to have such control here?

Comment: Yeah thats what the `ease-out` and other values are for... Already mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Added another animation class no-shadow with reverse styles.

```
@-webkit-keyframes no-shadow { /* Webkit */
    0%   { box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
    25%  { box-shadow: -3px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); }
    50%  { box-shadow: -2px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
    75%  { box-shadow: -1px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
    100% { box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
}
@-moz-keyframes no-shadow { /* Webkit */
    0%   { box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
    25%  { box-shadow: -3px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); }
    50%  { box-shadow: -2px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
    75%  { box-shadow: -1px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
    100% { box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
}
@keyframes no-shadow { /* Webkit */
    0%   { box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
    25%  { box-shadow: -3px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); }
    50%  { box-shadow: -2px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
    75%  { box-shadow: -1px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
    100% { box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
}

.no-shadow {
    animation:         no-shadow 2s forwards; /* CSS3 */
    -moz-animation:    no-shadow 2s forwards; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: no-shadow 2s forwards; /* Webkit */
}
```

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box");
function shadowHandle(){
 box.classList.toggle("shadow");
 box.classList.toggle("no-shadow");
}

box.addEventListener("click", shadowHandle);
```

```css
body{
  margin: 100px;
}
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shadow { /* Webkit */
 0%   { box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
 25%  { box-shadow: -1px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
 50%  { box-shadow: -2px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
 75%  { box-shadow: -3px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); }
 100% { box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
}
@-moz-keyframes shadow { /* Webkit */
 0%   { box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
 25%  { box-shadow: -1px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
 50%  { box-shadow: -2px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
 75%  { box-shadow: -3px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); }
 100% { box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
}
@keyframes shadow { /* Webkit */
 0%   { box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
 25%  { box-shadow: -1px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
 50%  { box-shadow: -2px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
 75%  { box-shadow: -3px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); }
 100% { box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
}
.shadow {
 animation:         shadow 2s forwards; /* CSS3 */
 -moz-animation:    shadow 2s forwards; /* Firefox */
 -webkit-animation: shadow 2s forwards; /* Webkit */
}

@-webkit-keyframes no-shadow { /* Webkit */
 0%   { box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
 25%  { box-shadow: -3px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); }
 50%  { box-shadow: -2px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
 75%  { box-shadow: -1px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
 100% { box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
}
@-moz-keyframes no-shadow { /* Webkit */
 0%   { box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
 25%  { box-shadow: -3px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); }
 50%  { box-shadow: -2px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
 75%  { box-shadow: -1px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
 100% { box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
}
@keyframes no-shadow { /* Webkit */
 0%   { box-shadow: -4px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
 25%  { box-shadow: -3px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); }
 50%  { box-shadow: -2px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
 75%  { box-shadow: -1px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
 100% { box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
}

.no-shadow {
 animation:         no-shadow 2s forwards; /* CSS3 */
 -moz-animation:    no-shadow 2s forwards; /* Firefox */
 -webkit-animation: no-shadow 2s forwards; /* Webkit */
}
```

```html
<div class="box shadow"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But i see same problem. If you look at shadow animating, you can see that shadow grow in steps, rather than smooth. Why is that so?

Comment: because you are using keyframes to create this animation. your changes take place at 25%,50% etc steps. try using transition property as suggested in other answers to get a smooth transition.

Comment: So this means, with keyframes you wont get smooth animations but you will get control of every step. With transition you get smooth animation but not so much control?

Comment: yeah kind of thats what i meant . :) try more smaller step example 10% and see if the animation smoothens!

Comment: Oh ok, now i get it. Thank you :). I thought they work the same just one with more controls. Than transition is the one for me :)